# Building Java Project with Hadoop-LZO but cannot find class

Tags: hadoop, javac, lzo

I'm trying to build a simple WordCount jar project which utilizes Hadoop-lzo library but cannot seem to get the following command to work, even though the class I'm referencing is within `hadoop classpath`:

```
$ javac -cp `hadoop classpath` *.java

LzoWordCount.java:76: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class LzoTextInputFormat
location: class LzoWordCount
      job.setInputFormatClass(LzoTextInputFormat.class);
                              ^
1 error
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that `LzoTextInputFormat` is part of the hadoop distro (which version are you using?) It appears to be part of a google code project named hadoop-gpl-compression - https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/hadoop-gpl-compression/

Comment: I am using Hadoop 2.0.0-cdh4.3.0. How would I include the correct .java or .class for my code to build?

Comment: LzotextInputFormat isn't listed in the Javadocs for CDH4u4: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/hadoop/api/ - Where did you acquire the class from?

Comment: I followed: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Ent/latest/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_LZO_Compression.html - and added the Parcel

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have correctly installed your LZO libraries (you should have `libgplcompression.so` in your `lib/natives/Linux**-**/` and the jar file in your `lib/` folder)

Since you have them the correct class should be `LzoDeprecatedTextInputFormat.class` or `LzoTextInputFormat.class` depending on wich API you use (According to your post you are using it right Job with LzoTextInputFormat).

So your problem could be in your java.library.path, wich should include path to your jar file. You can set it up in your `.bash_profile` or in you `bin/hadoop` file.
hope that helps.

Comment: I have tried directly adding the LzoTextInputFormat.class file into my project lib/ folder as well as actually including the LzoTextInputFormat.java source in my src/ folder, but neither works.

Comment: Sorry if I failed explaining myself but I meant include your `.jar` file (something like `hadoop-lzo-***.jar`) in your `java.library.path`. Because if you open this jar with vim you will see all the classes you need in it. I think there is also a way using the `-Djava.library.path=path/to/your/lzo/jar` in your programm command line. Hope that better helps.